# What's the point of having individual replication slots?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm getting confused about the reason to use individual replication slots for individual replicas(aside of a single point of crash). I get that each replication slot stores only some amount of WAL segments and if a replica goes offline replication slots guarantee that those segments that didn't get to the replica will be preserved until it goes back online. But doesn't it require less disk space to store segments up until the oldest checkpoint among all of the replicas?

As a very simplified example I have 3 replicas. First one is online and fully synced so let's say we don't store anything for this one. 2nd one gone offline 30 minutes ago so we store last 30 minutes of WAL. And the 3rd one is offline for 2 days so we store 2 days of WAL. What's the reason to store 2 days 30 minutes of WAL when we can simply store 2 days and save up on space?

Comment: To be clear the slots all point to the same source of WAL's, Each slot does not hold its set of WAL's. A slot is just a way to maintain information about where a particular replication is in the change stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slots don't store anything themselves.  They just do the accounting to let the system know how much to keep.

> What's the reason to store 2 days 30 minutes of WAL when we can simply store 2 days and save up on space?

What makes you think it **is** storing 2 days and 30 minutes rather than simply storing 2 days?

Comment: > What makes you think it is storing 2 days and 30 minutes rather than simply storing 2 days?

apparently a bad understanding of the design.

Thank you for you answer.